# Swift Mapping Custom Object Using Codable

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to practice mapping custom objects using swift & replace all manual mapping by using Codable. This concept is new to me but seems very worthwhile. In this project I want to fetch the user and make sure that all their data is stored in their User Document on firebase (including the custom object 'FavouriteItems'.

My User Model struct is:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct UserModel: Identifiable, Codable{
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var username : String
    var pic : String
    var bio: String
    var uid : String
    var isVerified: Bool
    var favouriteItems: [FavouriteItems]
}
```

My struct for an Item is:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import Firebase


struct Item: Identifiable, Codable {
    
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var item_name: String
    var item_type: String
    var item_image: String
    var item_details: String
    var item_uid : String
    var didFavourite: Bool? = false
    var isFavourite: Bool = false  
}
```

My struct for FavouriteItems is:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

//MARK: Make Hashable (See Tag Example)?
struct FavouriteItems: Identifiable, Codable {
    
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var item: Item
}
```

My fetch user function is (edited):

```
func fetchUser(uid: String, completion: @escaping (UserModel) -> ()){
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    let docRef = db.collection("Users").document(uid).getDocument(as: UserModel.self) { result in

        switch result {
        case .success(let user):
            // A `UserModel` value was successfully initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
            print("UserModel: \(user)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(user)
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            // A `UserModel` value could not be initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
            print("Error decoding UserModel: \(error)")
            // handle errors todo
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting errors in the fetchUser code including:

Cannot convert value of type 'UserModel.Type' to expected argument type 'FirestoreSource'

Contextual closure type '(DocumentSnapshot?, Error?) -> Void' expects 2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body

Incorrect argument label in call (have 'as:_:', expected 'source:completion:')

All of these errors occur on the line:

let docRef = db.collection("Users").document(uid).getDocument(as: UserModel.self) { result in

Here is my Podfile:

[image: Podfile]

Comment: Just an initial guess but that sounds like you have an old version of Firebase installed. Can you include your podfile, version of Cocoapods (pod --version) and version of Firebase? Also, are you `import FirebaseCore` and `import FirebaseFirestore`?

Comment: Make sure you're importing `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` in the file with the `fetchUser` method declared. The error is telling us that the compiler thinks you're trying to use the non-Codable aware `getDocument` method.

Comment: I will add my podfile to the question. I am not importing FirebaseCore or FirebaseFirestore in this project however in the file with the fetchUser method I am importing FirebaseFirestoreSwift.

Comment: Ok, looks like you are using some older verisons and setup. Please review [Add Firebase with CocoaPods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#cocoapods) as well as [Install Firebase in your Apple App](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/installation-methods#analytics-not-enabled) for integrating Firebase. Also, on the `getDocument` line, this `result in` should be `docRef.getDocument { document, error in`. See [Firebase Codable](https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/)

Comment: Im back working on this issue again. I have updated all pods but still am getting errors. I have updated the question to detail the errors and where they occur (where the fetchUser function is)